# Why can't I use (long) to promote an int?

Tags: java, variables, casting

```
long x = (long)(2147483649);
```

Why is this wrong? Why do I have to use L and F for floats and longs but I can use (byte) for example?

Comment: The int _literal_ is already too big so you can't create it in the first place. If you could the promotion would work.

Comment: because a numeric literal without modifier is getting identified as `int`. (the same happens for floating numeric values, which are identified as double). And since `2147483649` does not represent a valid `int` the compiler creates an error message.

Comment: Btw, the maximum value for `int` is 2147483647, i.e. 2 less then your number. You could try `long x = (long)(2147483647) + 2; ` ;)

Comment: How does using `(byte)` promote a value which is not valid either?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is technically related to Java specification. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10

> The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (2^31).
>
> All decimal literals from 0 to 2147483647 may appear anywhere an int
>   literal may appear. The decimal literal 2147483648 may appear only as
>   the operand of the unary minus operator - (§15.15.4).
>
> It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears
>   anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; or if
>   a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2^31).

Why?
because, as other people said before, in just 32 bits you can only represent  from -**2147483648** to **2147483647** (2^32 different numbers). So, before promoting it to long the compiler needs to be able to represent it, but it cannot. Indeed, java specification indicates that this is a compile-time error.
The largest decimal literal of type int is **2147483648** (2^31).

Just adding an L/l at the end of the literal (**2147483649L**), specifies that it is a literal of type long, and now it can contain bigger numbers.

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1). The suffix
>   L is preferred, because the letter l (ell) is often hard to
>   distinguish from the digit 1 (one).

So there are only two type of literal numbers in decimal format (for integer numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You **can**, but not this `int`. The number you are trying to cast is `80000001` in hex. This number is not a valid `int`.

This works because `2147483647` is `7fffffff` in hex - a perfgectly acceptable `int`.

```
    long x = (long)(2147483647);
```

Answer (score 0):

2147483649 = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 2

Can't fit that into an int variable. 
try `long x = 2147483649L;`

Answer (score 0):

Integer range is defined between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (**-2147483648** and **2147483647**)
your number **2147483649** is out of that range, therefore can not event be a valid integer

your compiler should even complains like:

[image]